# Bind f-key in use-package

Tags: key-bindings, use-package

How can I bind an f-key using jwiegley's `use-package` package? Any of these combinations produces an error:

```
 :bind ("f11" . multi-term)
 :bind (<f11> . multi-term)
 :bind ([f11] . multi-term)
```

(Of course, this falls under the scope of a `use-package` declaration.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to quote `"<f11>"`, like this:

```
:bind ("<f11>" . multi-term)
```

And here's a full example, with ace-jump-mode:

```
(use-package ace-jump-mode
         :commands ace-jump-mode
         :init
         :bind ("<f7>" . ace-jump-mode))
```

Comment: Just for the record, ace-jump-mode is autoloaded, so this code is equivalent to a single global-set-key.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to say that there's value in top-level `global-set-key`
statements.  In the screenshot below, I'm able to jump around my Emacs
config, including jumping to `global-set-key` statements. You can see
that it matches just `ace` in all my config files.

And one more thing: many commands, such as `ace-jump-mode` are autoloaded
so you can just bind them without `require` or `use-package`.

[image]

The function to jump is `lispy-goto` from [lispy](https://github.com/abo-abo/lispy).

Comment: Two tangential remarks : (i) I like use-package because it helps grouping all related settings in one place, so I use it even when not strictly needed. (ii) Even when not using use-package, you can also use bind-key directly. This makes M-x describe-personal-keybindings RET a useful command.