# Bind function key when in python-mode

Tags: key-bindings, use-package

I want to bind `f5` to launch pdb, but the minibuffer always says `<f5>` is undefined.

```
(use-package python-mode
  :bind (:map python-mode-map
          ("<[f5]>" . realgud:pdb))
  :config
  (load-library 'realgud))
```

Comment: Maybe try `(kbd "<f5>")` ?

Comment: @NickD It wants arguments acceptable to the `bind-keys` function, so that doesn't work.

Comment: Does the vector form `[f5]` work? In case, it's not clear, I know nothing about `use-package`, so you might want to ignore me and wait for somebody who knows something about it.

Comment: No, that gives a parse error. I got this syntax from https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/bind-f-key-in-use-package

Comment: Does that `(:map...)` sexp need to be quoted? Or more likely, does the cons `("<[f5]>" . realgud:pdb)` need to be quoted? The question you cited shows no quotation, but it also doesn't show that you can use a `:map` sexp.

[IMHO it's too bad that things like `use-package` (apparently) introduce another syntax for key binding. The existing syntax is already confusing enough.)]

Comment: I don't think he gets an error: it's just not effective.

Comment: @Drew I'm following examples from the `use-package` readme. I'm not even sure if the `:map` is required tho.

Comment: Since there are no answers so far, and from what you say this should be straightforward `use-package` usage, I wonder whether something else is interfering. Do you get the same behavior if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file) and you evaluate that `use-package` code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(use-package python-mode
  :bind (:map python-mode-map
          ([f5] . realgud:pdb)))
```

I can't see any reason why this would not work, but I should note that it's derived from my specific usage, which is slightly different.

I collect all my F-key bindings in an alist, directly calling `bind-key` on the `car` and `cdr` of each element. `bind-key` is what a `:bind` stanza in a `use-package` declaration expands to.

```
(defun ph/map-keys (key-mappings)
  "Bind keys using alist KEY-MAPPINGS."
  (dolist (key-mapping key-mappings)
    (let ((key-chord (car key-mapping)) (command (cdr key-mapping)))
      (when (and key-chord command (commandp command))
        (bind-key key-chord command)))))
```

The simple vector form `[f5]` works there for plain F-key bindings like `([f5] . my-command)` (as suggested by @NickD in a comment above). Modifiers need slightly more complex syntax: `([(control f5)] . my-command)`.

Comment: `f5` is still undefined

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is simply to bind a key in a given mode, `use-package` isn't the only road to Rome.

As long as the mode map variable is defined, `define-key` is also an option:

`(define-key python-mode-map [f6] 'my-other-special-function)`

If there is a need to test things out you might define an interactive function and use `local-set-key`.

```
;; Try invoking this once in python mode.
(defun bind-f5-in-python-mode ()
  (interactive)
  (local-set-key [f5] 'my-special-function))
```